# react-native-hms-location error when building app

Tags: javascript, react-native, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to install the library @hmscore/react-native-hms-location. I am following all the steps as per https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/integrating-sdk-0000001050041330

However, once i have installed the library and I attempt to run `./gradlew assembleRelease` in order to build my app, I get the following error in the terminal:

```
/MainApplication.java:18: error: cannot find symbol import com.huawei.hms.rn.location.RNHMSLocationPackage;
```

I  don't understand why, because I am following the instructions.

Anyone else seen this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for pointing out this issue. We have provided a fix already and it will be on the next release.

There is a bug from the current plug-in code, which affects the compilation. Developers need to manually adjust the plug-in code.

Then I tried to make some changes on the code:

1. Move the RNHMSLocationPackage.java file to location folder:

[image]

2. Update the code in RNHMSLocationPackage.java：

[image]

3. Update the Androidmanifest file in android/src/main folder:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.huawei.hms.location">

</manifest>
```

According to my previous verification, this modification will be successful.

**Update:**

The brand new version of React Native Location Plugin 5.0.0.301 is available, please kindly refer to [React Native Plugin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Library/rn-sdk-download-0000001050041368).

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Do you know when the new release will come out ?

Comment: @NdaJunior Yes, here is the new [plugin version of RN Location Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Library/rn-sdk-download-0000001050041368?ha_source=hms1).